# SlowAES decryption errors in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, encryption, aes

i have the following AES encryption function in c#

```
public class AES
{
    private AesManaged AESCipher;
    private String Password;
    private int Iterations;
    private byte[] Salt;

    public AES(String Password)
    {
        this.AESCipher = new AesManaged();
        this.AESCipher.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        this.AESCipher.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        this.AESCipher.IV = HexStringToByteArray("000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F");
        this.AESCipher.KeySize = 256;
        this.AESCipher.BlockSize = 128;
        this.Iterations = 1000;
        this.Salt = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("saltsalt");
        this.Password = Password;
    }

    public String Encrypt(String PlainText)
    {
        this.AESCipher.Key = GenerateKey();
        byte[] plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PlainText);
        ICryptoTransform transform = this.AESCipher.CreateEncryptor();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(transform.TransformFinalBlock(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length));
    }

    public String Decrypt(String CipherText)
    {
        this.AESCipher.Key = GenerateKey();
        byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(CipherText);
        ICryptoTransform transform = this.AESCipher.CreateDecryptor();
        return System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(transform.TransformFinalBlock(cipherTextBytes, 0, cipherTextBytes.Length));
    }

    private static string ByteArrayToHexString(byte[] b)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb1 = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
        {
            sb1.Append(System.String.Format("{0:X2}", b[i]));
        }
        return sb1.ToString().ToUpper();
    }

    private static byte[] HexStringToByteArray(string s)
    {
        var r = new byte[s.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i += 2)
        {
            r[i / 2] = (byte)Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        }
        return r;
    }

    private byte[] GenerateKey()
    {
        var rfc2898 = new System.Security.Cryptography.Rfc2898DeriveBytes(this.Password, this.Salt, this.Iterations);
        return rfc2898.GetBytes(this.AESCipher.KeySize / 8);
    }
}
```

With the above function, i obtain a base64-encoded string "HlHY8Y2v6idG2DoDMgvR/Q==" from the word "hello".

Then i use the following decryption function in Javascript, using slowAES library and other stuff like cryptohelpers.js and pbkdf2.js :

```
function decrypt3() {
        var mypbkdf2 = new PBKDF2("password", "saltsalt", 1000, 32);
        var newKey;
        var result_callback = function (key) {
            newKey = key;
            var bytes = cryptoHelpers.base64.decode('HlHY8Y2v6idG2DoDMgvR/Q==');

            var result = slowAES.decrypt(bytes, 6, slowAES.modeOfOperation.CBC, hexStringToByteArray(key), 32, hexStringToByteArray("000102030405060708090A0B0C0D0E0F"));
            alert(byteArrayToAscii(result));


        };
        mypbkdf2.deriveKey(function () {}, result_callback);
    }



 function asciiToByteArray(s)
{
    var r= Array(s.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
    {
        r[i]= s.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return r;
}

function byteArrayToAscii(a) {
    var r = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        r += String.fromCharCode(a[i]);
    }
    return r;
}

function hexStringToByteArray(s) {
    try { hexcase } catch (e) { hexcase = 0; }
    var hex_tab = hexcase ? "0123456789ABCDEF" : "0123456789abcdef";
    var r = Array(s.length / 2);
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i += 2) {
        r[i / 2] = parseInt(s.substr(i, 2), 16);
    }
    return r;
}

function byteArrayToHexString(a) {
    try { hexcase } catch (e) { hexcase = 0; }
    var hex_tab = hexcase ? "0123456789ABCDEF" : "0123456789abcdef";
    var r = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        var b = hex_tab.charAt((a[i] >> 4) & 0x0F) +
            hex_tab.charAt(a[i] & 0x0F);
        r += b;
    }
    return r;
}
```

I can't decrypt the string, the 'result' is always an empty array, i can't figured it out. Thank you for helping!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to decrypt aes ciphertext with slowaes (javascript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123641/unable-to-decrypt-aes-ciphertext-with-slowaes-javascript)

Comment: Nope, the issue in that question was that he was passing his IV as a string instead of a byte array. The OP is not making the same mistake.